# add cookie if no cookie of that name exists jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a splash page where the user chooses between 2 experiences. once chosen, a cookie is added so they will always get that experience (or at least for the next 30 days). however, if a user comes to the site directly to a sub-url and bypasses the splash page, they should be automatically added to the default experience and get the default cooke (theme1). everything except the default cookie part is working.

here's what i have:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
$('.theme2').click(function() {     
    createCookie('chooseTheme','chosenTheme2',30)       
});
$('.theme1').click(function() {     
    createCookie('chooseTheme','chosenTheme1',30)       
}); 
var x = readCookie('chooseTheme');
if ($.cookie('chooseTheme') === null) {
    createCookie('chooseTheme','chosenTheme1',30);      
} 
if (x.indexOf('chosenTheme1') > -1) {
    $('body').addClass('themeOne');
} else if (x.indexOf('chosenTheme2') > -1) {
    $('body').addClass('themeTwo');
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running a loop that updates every 1 minute. During the update, it triggers the function that checks for the cookie like the following:

```
setInterval(checkCookie(), 60000);
//the 60000 is for 60000 milliseconds which is 1 minute.
function checkCookie() {
    var x = readCookie('chooseTheme');
    if ($.cookie('chooseTheme') === null) {
    createCookie('chooseTheme','chosenTheme1',30);      
    } 
    if (x.indexOf('chosenTheme1') > -1) {
        $('body').addClass('themeOne');
    } else if (x.indexOf('chosenTheme2') > -1) {
    $('body').addClass('themeTwo');
    }
}
```

Then add the code above into your code and it will check for the theme every 1 minute. I hope this helps you.

Comment: is there a way to avoid the loop and just do this on load? cause it should only matter on page load.

Comment: Well you could set a variable and if the theme has been read from the cookie, it changes to 'true', and by default it is false. 1 minute after the user comes on, if the variable is still false, re run the script, so then the loop for checking that variable is not 100% constant. Then again though, I don't really see anything wrong with running the loop. Unless you have something specific that would be affected.

Comment: The true/false variable worked. though i didn't use the interval (since if you end up at the page and there's no cookie for whatever reason my code threw up an error that several browsers didn't like. Thanks!